# how distributed cloud storage works with ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, dapps, storage

Distributed Cloud storage is a great concept , I have been doing a lot of search on this topic but couldn't get the exact information i am looking for:-

How the projects like Storj are using the Ethereum blockchain, what minimal data is stored on the blockchain?
How these distributed file systems manage data ,storage and retrieval of data ?
How exactly smart contracts are useful in these kind of Dapps?